# How to flip image from QCamera?

Tags: c++, qcamera

In QT Creator how we can filp the images from camera. I googled a lot but I didn't get a proper solution.
Following is my code.

```
mCamera = new QCamera;
    mViewfinder = new QCameraViewfinder;
    mLayout = new QVBoxLayout(ui->graphicsView);
    mLayout->addWidget(mViewfinder);
    mCamera->setViewfinder(mViewfinder);
    mViewfinder->show();
    mCamera->start();
```

I tried  QCamera::FrontFace and QCamera::BackFace in constructor argument in QCamera like below

```
mCamera = new QCamera(QCamera::FrontFace);
```

and

```
mCamera = new QCamera(QCamera::BackFace );
```

But both have no difference.
In Python

```
video=cv2.flip(self.frame,1)
```

will solve the problem,
Any idea how to solve this ..
I am using Windows 10

Comment: You're using OpenCV also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**QCamera::FrontFace** and **QCamera::BackFace** are just [positions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcamera.html#Position-enum) of the camera. To achieve what you want, you should flip every image.

Create **QCameraImageCapture** and connect to its **imageCaptured()** signal.

```cpp
auto imageCapture = new QCameraImageCapture( mCamera );
connect(imageCapture, &QCameraImageCapture::imageCaptured, [&](int id, const QImage &preview){
    QImage flipped = preview.mirrored();
    // do what you want with flipped image
})
```

[Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#mirrored) says that **mirrored(bool horizontal = false, bool vertical = true)**

> Returns a mirror of the image, mirrored in the horizontal and/or the vertical direction depending on whether horizontal and vertical are set to true or false.

**UPDATE:**

I found the camera and tested the code and realized that I forgot one important thing. You need to use a timer by which **QCameraImageCapture** will capture the image.

Create **QTimer** and connect to `QTimer::timeout()` signal:

```cpp
connect (&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&](){
    camera->searchAndLock();
    imageCapture->capture();
    camera->unlock();
});
```

And after that start the timer. To show flipped image you can use just **QLabel** class with `label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(flipped))` method.

Comment: i changed the code as per your answer but nothing is in graphicsView item displayed.i edited my answer and added your code also..

Comment: Is the _mCamera_ available? Check its state after starting. Also you can try to connect to **errorOccurred()** signal. Unfortunately, right now I don't have a camera to test. But I think that the problem in **QCamera** initialization. Try to load cameras with `QCameraInfo::availableCameras()` and use one of them. Also, try to move `mCamera->start()` to the end of function.

Comment: i am using my laps webcam, it has no problem, still now also it works with my old code.

Comment: I updated the answer and tested on the camera I found.

Comment: I updated my code with label widget (videoFrame) and did as you told. But no luck, My question is updated with new code. Is it is correct?

Comment: No, you should start the timer after the connections. And if you are using this code as class method, I think you should move *imageCamera* definition to class definition and use it as a field of class, like *mCamera* to get rid of memory leak.

Comment: thanks for your help, and the code is worked for me..... In "QImage flipped = preview.mirrored(true,false);"I added "true" and "false" parameters, otherwise the image is shown inverted..

Answer (score 1):

Hai I changed my code as per the answer of @Allocse and its work for me
My full code will be

```
mCamera = new QCamera;
    mCamera->start();
    imageCapture = new QCameraImageCapture( mCamera );
    connect (&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&](){
    mCamera->searchAndLock();
    imageCapture->capture();
    mCamera->unlock();
    });
    connect(imageCapture, &QCameraImageCapture::imageCaptured, [&](int id, const QImage &preview){
    QImage flipped = preview.mirrored(true,false);

    ui->videoFrame->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(flipped));
    });
     timer.start();
```

Note :-mCamera and  imageCapture should be declared in class decleration